# Disable clicking future date and set grey color in p-calendar angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to disable clicking future dates and set those future dates with grey color background. but disabling not working, set grey color is working fine. any idea about this issue.

HTML file:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="dateInDateFormat" [monthNavigator]="true"
                        [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="1970:2099" [dateFormat]="const.dateFormatCal"
                        formControlName="daateFromControl" dataType="string">
                        <ng-template pTemplate="date" let-date>
                          <div *ngIf="checkFutureDate(date);then highlightedDate else normalDate"></div>
                          <ng-template #highlightedDate>
                              <span [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: 'inherit'}" style="border-radius:75%">{{date.day}}</span>
                          </ng-template>
                          <ng-template #normalDate>
                                  <span [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: '#d3d3d3'}" style="border-radius:75%">{{date.day}}</span>
                          </ng-template>
                  
                      </ng-template></p-calendar>
```

TypeScript:

```
  checkFutureDate(date:any){
    var calendarDate = new Date(date.year,date.month,date.day);
    calendarDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
   console.log(""+calendarDate+""+(calendarDate < this.todayDate));
    return calendarDate < this.todayDate;
  }
```

output:

[image]

I tried `[maxDate]="todayDate"` it is working fine for disabling but set grey color not working. Someone pls provide input

Comment: If you set the max/minDate the component styles the input by itself, what are you trying to do differently than [this example with min/max](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo-zgtb3p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts)?

Comment: @NilsKähler m trying to add grey color to maxDates(disabled date)

Answer (score 1):

You can set a custom styling for the disabled elements in the p-calendar component with the `p-disabled` class.

Setting the `background-color` to grey on this, should give you a grey background color for the disabled fields.

[image: Grey background color]

HTML:

```html
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date" 
            [minDate]="minDate" 
            [maxDate]="maxDate" 
            [readonlyInput]="true" 
            inputId="min-max" 
            styleClass="custom-theme">
</p-calendar>
```

CSS:

```
.custom-theme .p-disabled {
  background: grey !important;
}
```

This can be demoed [here on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo-zgtb3p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working for me, I tried the style in my app.scss file but no luck. for p.disabled of p-calendar class do we need to add anything in scss file

Comment: @UserLearning You probably need to set the viewEncapsulation.None on your component, or set `::ng-deep .p-disabled` to make the style bleed into p-calendar.

Comment: yes, tried both.

Comment: @UserLearning What problem are you encoutering, can you inspect the dom, to see if the class is set? Did you add the styleClass and if then added it both places, can you se if the css is overitten with something else.  Did you try to remove the unused templates from your html?